# Can I detect devices on the network using UDP?

Tags: android, networking, udp

I'm pretty new to this so I may not make sense but ask me to clarify!

This is pretty vague, but what I currently have is a device connected to the same ethernet network that my PC is connected to.
What I am trying to do is detect that device using UDP and somehow display the "connection" on my android app.
The thing I'm confused about though is that the "device" is just a simple circuit board looking thing with the ethernet port attached to it. So I'm not really sure what to look/search for.

I have no idea how to approach this, are there any resources or advice you can give me?
I've gotten advice to use Wireshark to detect connections but I'm not sure what that really means in this context... does it mean when I send out a UDP broadcast signal or something like that, wireshark will be able to see the device responding?

Thanks!

Comment: "_What I am trying to do is detect that device using UDP and somehow display the "connection" on my android app._" UDP is explicitly _connectionless_, so there is no such thing as a UDP connection.

Answer (score 0):

The device that you described with an ethernet port attached to it is having a TCP/IP driver which enables it to communicate through a TCP/IP network.

I think your problem is how to capture the traffic between your device and android.

I suggest using a network HUB or a managed switch that supports port mirroring. Connect your Ethernet-enabled circuit board (sorry I don't know exactly what device you are using, maybe a raspberry PI?) to a HUB or managed switch together with a PC or laptop with Wireshark installed. You should be able to capture "Ethernet" traffic in Wireshark.

Note: Wireshark display capture might be a little confusing since it will display all network traffic flowing in-out of the network segment. I suggest using a Wireshark display filter. ex. ip.addr==your.target.ip.address && udp.port==your_udp_port_number.